# Calling Web Service from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services

I have a simple web service hosted in IIS. I am calling it from within a stored procedure in SQL Server. The web service has just one method

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string HelloWorld()
 {
        return "Hello World";
 }
```

It returns the xml:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>
```

When executing the stored procedure:

```
SET @Url = 'http://localhost:61004/Default Web Service/WebService1.asmx/
   HelloWorld';

EXEC sp_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @Url, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT

SELECT @Xml = CAST(@response as xml)

Select @xml

EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
```

I got this error:

> Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use CONVERT with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the error message and do as it tells you to! You need to replace your `CAST`

```
SELECT @Xml = CAST(@response as xml)
```

with this instead:

```
SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, @response, 2)
```

It seems that your XML somehow causes grief when using `CAST` - but with the `CONVERT` and style = 2, many of those situations can be handled properly

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used CONVERT instead of CAST. Now got this error message.    XML parsing: line 28, character 65, A string literal was expected
XML DTD has been stripped from one or more XML fragments.  External subsets, if any, have been ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following in the web.config file.

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
 <webServices>
     <protocols>
         <add name="HttpGet"/>
         <add name="HttpPost"/>
     </protocols>
 </webServices>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Both the sql statements worked.

```
SELECT @Xml = CAST(@response as xml)
SELECT @Xml = CONVERT(XML, @response, 2)
```

I changed the path to call to Web Service.

```
SET @Url = 'http://localhost:61004/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld';
```

Then it worked!!! and returned the xml string.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>
```