# Using XPath expressions inside SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xpath

I am trying to use an XPath expression to select nodes or node-sets in an XML document inside a SQL Server stored procedure.

I am trying to do something similar to code in c#

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

 XmlNode contact = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//users/user/contact");
 string strContact = contact.InnerText.Trim();
```

The XML is a result of call to Web Service from within a stored procedure.

Similar to this example.
[Calling Web Service from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734821/calling-web-service-from-stored-procedure)

However the XML looks like this:

```
<DocumentElement xmlns="">
  <stats>
    <delivered>5</delivered>
  </stats>
</DocumentElement>
```

I need to retrieve the value of the node delivered using a statement similar to

```
XmlNode delivered = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//stats/delivered");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're obviously ignoring the **XML namespace** that's defined on your root element - you need to **respect** that XML namespace and include it in your query!

```
-- Sample data - using a *SAMPLE* namespace - replace with your own!
DECLARE @input XML = '<DocumentElement xmlns="urn:sample-namespace">
  <stats>
    <delivered>5</delivered>
  </stats>
</DocumentElement>'

-- set up a query that *uses* that XML namespace instead of ignoring it...
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'urn:sample-namespace')
SELECT
    @input.value('(/DocumentElement/stats/delivered)[1]', 'int')
```